# Как установить pytorch?

Tags: python, pip, python-3.7, conda

Не могу установить pytorch.
Пытался через pip и conda и ничего не получилось, выдает ошибки.

pip:

```
C:\Users\пк>pip3 install torch===1.3.0 torchvision===0.4.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch===1.3.0 (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch===1.3.0

C:\Users\пк>pip3 install torch==1.3.0+cpu torchvision==0.4.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.3.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.3.0+cpu
```

conda:

```
C:\Users\пк>conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - cpuonly
    - pytorch
    - torchvision


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    cpuonly-1.0                |                0           2 KB  pytorch
    ninja-1.9.0                |   py37h74a9793_0         238 KB
    pytorch-1.3.0              |      py3.7_cpu_0        57.4 MB  pytorch
    torchvision-0.4.1          |         py37_cpu         2.1 MB  pytorch
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        59.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  cpuonly            pytorch/noarch::cpuonly-1.0-0
  ninja              pkgs/main/win-64::ninja-1.9.0-py37h74a9793_0
  pytorch            pytorch/win-64::pytorch-1.3.0-py3.7_cpu_0
  torchvision        pytorch/win-64::torchvision-0.4.1-py37_cpu


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
cpuonly-1.0          | 2 KB      | ############################################################################ | 100%
torchvision-0.4.1    | 2.1 MB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
ninja-1.9.0          | 238 KB    | ############################################################################ | 100%
pytorch-1.3.0        | 57.4 MB   | ############################################################################ | 100%

InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\Users\\пк\\.conda\\pkgs\\cpuonly-1.0-0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nFailed to open 'C:\\Users\\пк\\.conda\\pkgs\\cpuonly-1.0-0.tar.bz2'")
InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\Users\\пк\\.conda\\pkgs\\torchvision-0.4.1-py37_cpu.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nFailed to open 'C:\\Users\\пк\\.conda\\pkgs\\torchvision-0.4.1-py37_cpu.tar.bz2'")
InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\Users\\пк\\.conda\\pkgs\\ninja-1.9.0-py37h74a9793_01z8xlkhu\\info-ninja-1.9.0-py37h74a9793_0.tar.zst.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nFailed to open 'C:\\Users\\пк\\.conda\\pkgs\\ninja-1.9.0-py37h74a9793_01z8xlkhu\\info-ninja-1.9.0-py37h74a9793_0.tar.zst'")
InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive C:\\Users\\пк\\.conda\\pkgs\\pytorch-1.3.0-py3.7_cpu_0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nFailed to open 'C:\\Users\\пк\\.conda\\pkgs\\pytorch-1.3.0-py3.7_cpu_0.tar.bz2'")
```

Comment: @gil9red  Exception: You tried to install "pytorch". The package named for PyTorch is "torch"

Comment: Проблема может быть с кириллицей в пути

Comment: @gil9red В каком пути?

Comment: `C:\\Users\\пк\\.conda`

Comment: @gil9red И что предложите сделать?